# Why is my Error Handler only working once?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to cycle through all the worksheets in a specific workbook and attempting to copy formatting from one worksheet to another.  The objective here is to find the corresponding worksheet, which has the same name but is appended by "(FF)".  Then I want to copy that Sheet's format to the sheet that doesn't contain the appended version of "(FF)".  Unfortunately, not all sheets contain it's corresponding sheet with the appended "(FF)".  That being said, I've written the Macro below to help me blow through any "Subscript out of range" errors by way of sending it to an Error Handler.  The problem is, when testing this out on a workbook where no sheet has a corresponding sheet appended by "(FF)" it only blows through the first "Subscript out of range" error and that's it.

Why is my Error Handler only working once?

```
Sub InitializeFormat()

    Dim ws As Worksheet


    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If Right(ws.Name, 4) <> "(FF)" Then
            On Error GoTo SheetDoesNotExist
            Sheets(ws.Name & "(FF)").Cells.Copy
            Sheets(ws.Name).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats
        End If
SheetDoesNotExist:
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not resuming from your error. There are a couple of technical issues with your code. Try this:

```
    Sub InitializeFormat()
    On Error GoTo SheetDoesNotExist

        Dim ws As Worksheet


        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If Right(ws.Name, 4) <> "(FF)" Then
                Sheets(ws.Name & "(FF)").Cells.Copy
                Sheets(ws.Name).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats
            End If
    NextSheet:
         Next ws
         Exit Sub
    SheetDoesNotExist:
        Resume NextSheet

    End Sub
```

Now when you get an error, you HANDLE it by RESUMING (Which clears the error). If you do not receive an error, the program will exit before it reaches the error handler.

Comment: Genius!  Thank you for the help.  I'll take note of this structure for future reference.